# How to bind image's tooltip to exception error message in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Here's my code that is supposed to immitate WinForm's ErrorProvider for WPF:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="1" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                        </Border>
                        <Image Source="Images/dialog_error.png" Width="30" ToolTip="{Binding ElementName=adornedElement, 
                     Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors), 
                     Converter={k:ValidationErrorsToStringConverter}}"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                           Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>    
</Window.Resources>
```

I want it to display an error icon with a tooltip explaining what's wrong.

The error icon is being displayed, but the tooltip is missing.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to set name on `<AdornedElementPlaceholder />`. It should be `<AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="adornedElement" />` otherwise your `Binding ElementName=adornedElement` won't work